# Limit of a sequence does not converge to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+2}\ne 0.$$
I proved it as followed
$$|L-a_n|\ge\epsilon$$
$$|0-\frac{n}{n+2}|\ge\epsilon$$
$$\frac{n}{n+2}\ge\epsilon$$
$$n\ge\epsilon n+2\epsilon$$
$$n(1-\epsilon)\ge2\epsilon$$
$$n\ge\frac{2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}.$$
Is this proof correct? Because I can just switch the sign $\geq$ to $<$ it looks like the series converges to $0$ since
$$|L-a_n|\lt\epsilon$$
$$|0-\frac{n}{n+2}|\lt\epsilon$$
$$\frac{n}{n+2}\lt\epsilon$$
$$n\lt\epsilon n+2\epsilon$$
$$n(1-\epsilon)\lt2\epsilon$$
$$n\lt\frac{2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}.$$

Comment: How does the second one prove convergence?

Comment: The second approach evaluates $\lim_{n\to0}\frac{n}{n+2}$.

Comment: Please fix the title, it should say "zero" and not "one". Also, the sequence converges to the limit, the limit doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $\,\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{n+2}\neq0\;$ you should prove that there exists $\,\varepsilon^*>0\,$ such that for any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ there exists $\,n_k>k\,$ such that

$\left|\dfrac{n_k}{n_k+2}\right|\geqslant\varepsilon^*\;.$

In fact, there exists $\,\varepsilon^*=\dfrac12>0\,$ such that for any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ there exists $\,n_k=k+2>k\,$ such that

$\left|\dfrac{n_k}{n_k+2}\right|=\dfrac{n_k}{n_k+2}=\dfrac{k+2}{k+4}\geqslant\dfrac{k+2}{2k+4}=\dfrac12=\varepsilon^*\;.$

Answer (score 0):

In the present form your proof looks very confused.

Notably how is the condition $|L-a_n|\ge\varepsilon$ related to the fact to be proved?

More simply we can proceed by contradiction, assuming that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+2}=0$$

then by definition we should have

$$\forall \varepsilon>0\;\; \exists n_0 \;\; \forall n\ge n_0\;\; \frac{n}{n+2}\le \varepsilon$$

but $\forall n\ge 1$ we have $a_n=\frac{n}{n+2}\ge \frac13$, indeed

$$a_{n+1}>a_n \iff \frac{n+1}{n+3}>\frac{n}{n+2} \iff 3n+2>3n$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{n} = \frac{n}{n+2} \geq \frac{1}{2} ~ \forall n \geq 2 \implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} \geq \frac{1}{2} > 0$. So, it can't converge to $0$.